# I upgraded the system and I forgot to remove the problematic package

Tags: package-management, backup, performance

I forgot to remove the problematic package `python3-uno` and I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10. Now I cannot install programs as before.

The problem is in `python3` packages, which prevent me from installing and running certain programs.

I cannot run Synaptic, TimeShift, all backup programs decently, but, fortunately, there is one backup that can resolve the problem. However, I don't know how I can restore the system using the terminal.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try as I might I have no idea what this means. *I don't can to run the synaptic, timeshift, all backup programs, What are the certain programs you can not run if we do not know we can not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When turning on your computer, you should get a grub screen that has the option to boot in safe mode.(*Here it is **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** *)

[image: pic1]

Select that and it would take you to a bare terminal with root privileges. You can then [Run Timeshift from terminal](https://dev.to/rahedmir/how-to-use-timeshift-from-command-line-in-linux-1l9b)

Comment: Be careful not overdoing things with root privileges in this mode. Just restore the snapshot and shutdown the computer using `shutdown now` and then boot up normally

Comment: So, When I execute the timeshift on the terminal (without enter in safe mode), for some reason, the timeshift don't restore the backup because of limit number of attempts and because When I write “next”, the program don't to does nothing to restore the backup, someone knows How to resolve it? Although, looks to be one good solution to enter in safe mode

Comment: @EduardoBernal , You have to run timeshift with root privileges. Enter into root user with `sudo su`

Comment: I entered as root and the problem strangely to continue the same, I don't know if the program timeshift this with problems, because I don't can to execute the timeshift only on workspace, if the timeshift were normal, maybe will haven't this problem

Comment: Did you try from safe mode or from normal mode ? @EduardoBernal

Comment: I went to see on the internet How to open the timeshift by the terminal, and finally I got open the timeshift using the command on the terminal: sudo timeshift-gtk, strangely, this functioned. Remembering When happened it, I was in normal mode

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install two programs to help in anything of these emergency, Timeshift (backup program) and Stacer (PC optimizer):

Timeshift — He uses the rsync to make backups, where you to control and change the system, so, watch out! OBS: Remember you have to wait the restoring finish before to do anything other thing, as write on PC (same it's accidental). And stay on guard to corruptn't the restoring, don't nothing when the system restoring were happening.

Stacer — He optimizes the system using very options, He until removes packages, this is important because if you use together with timeshift and for example packages are broke, and you don't get to resolve, you can restore the system, and you can remove the packages that are broke

Case you don't can to execute this programs for some reason, write the name of the program, if you don't can, search on internet the name program, and you can to execute normally the timeshift, and it can to go back to the previous situation, where the PC was normal